# How to read a file in java element by element

Tags: java, file

I have a file which's structure is

```
#n aa bb cc
```

Where `n` is the number of elements in the row, and `aa` is an element(there's always space between them).

So I would like to know of there's a way to read the n and then element by element during some rows.

Comment: There is a way, but we'd like to see how you did it, first.

Comment: Agreed, try to come up with a solution on your own. Here's an idea to get you going: read the file line by line, then write some code to parse each line in Java.

Comment: I love it when one gives a good advice of putting in some efforts to OP and next moment there are plethora of solution pouring in from other SO users.

Comment: What I was trying to do was read each line and save it into a string, then try to get each part using substring. The problem that I have is that the number of elements on each row is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
Read the file in line at a time
Split the line by space
["#n", "aa", "bb", "cc"]
take the substring of the first element to exclude the # and parse an integer from it
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has built in support for `Regular Expressions` using `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`. These are the tools you need.